# Sending emails to multiple recipients containing different data from single record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I need to send an email to a list of vendors.  The email needs to contain only the information pertaining to that vendor.  For example, cabinet details and specifications = cabinet vendor, flooring details and specifications = flooring vendor etc.  All of the information from the database is from a single record.  Is this possible?  RTFG (reading the f google) has not been successful thus far.  If it is possible, where can I find and/or start looking for documentation for this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly its possible.  Two ways to go:  assuming you don't have models defined for vendors, but are just pulling data from the record you are talking about you could do this:

```
class VendorMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def self.send_mail(project)
    cabinet_vendor_mail.deliver(project)
    flooring_vendor_mail.deliver(project)
    # etc
  end

  def cabinet_vendor_mail(project)
    # set up your instance variables and send a mail using a view specific to this vendor type
  end

  # etc
end
```

That would be the big hammer approach...  better would be develop a vendor class and then set up a relationship between vendors and projects.

Then you can have a proper vendor mailer that looks at the vendor type and sends the appropriate message type.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to send emails is with Rails' Action Mailer, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html. In your case you would want to create an ActionMailer that would handle various templates to be sent depending on who you are sending them to. All of these can take in the same variable and use them in their templates differently because they are different templates.

Create an ActionMailer that will house your emailing methods. The methods themselves look the same now but that is to tell Rails which template to use.

```
class VendorMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def cabinet_email(vendor, specifications)
    @vendor = vendor
    @specifications = specifications
    mail(to: @vendor.email, subject: 'New Specifications')
  end

 def flooring_email(vendor, specifications)
    @vendor = vendor
    @specifications = specifications
    mail(to: @vendor.email, subject: 'New Specifications')
  end
end
```

Now create a template for each of those methods that uses the specifications differently.

**app/views/vendor_mailer/cabinet_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>New specifications for you, <%= @vendor.name %></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><%= @specification.floor.width %></li>
        <li>...</li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your controller just loop through and shoot off the various emails to all of the people that need to be informed.

```
class SpecificationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @specifications = Specifications.new(params[:specifications])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @specifications.save
        # Tell the VendorMailer to send emails after save
        # Look up correct vendor before these calls!
        VendorMailer.cabinet_email(vendor_cabinet, @specifications).deliver
        VendorMailer.flooring_email(vendor_flooring, @specifications).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to(@specifications, notice: 'Specifications were successfully created.') }
        format.json { render json: @specifications, status: :created, location: @specifications }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @specifications.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Those are some basics that should get you in the right direction without using any extra gems.